# Can I connect from Titanium Developer Desktop App to postgresql?

Tags: titanium

Let me know. How can I connect from Titanium Desktop Application to postgresql database?

Thanks
Nge

Comment: you should be able to do it in the Desktop through PHP, Ruby, or Python but I've never tried TiDesktop so I'm not positive

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you can use dl() to load a php extension for postgres + pdo_postgres if you use PDO. Be carefull on multiplatform deply to have correct extension module compile flags on Windows and mac.